# sfdx force:source:push Issue

Tags: salesforcedx, circleci

I am using CircleCI to implement continuous integration, and am following the Salesforce DX documentation closely.

I have a very large managed package that I am trying to push to a scratch org as part of the automated build-and-test.

The sfdx force:source:push command fails, though.  Is my package too big or is there something else going on?

Here is the config.yml section I am executing:

```
  - run:
      name: Setup Org
      command: |
        echo 'Running tests'
        ls -al
        sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid $HUB_CONSUMER_KEY --jwtkeyfile assets/server.key --username $HUB_SFDC_USER --setdefaultdevhubusername -a hub            
        sfdx force --help
        sfdx force:org:create -s -f .circleci/project-scratch-def.json -a circle_build_$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM --wait 4
        sfdx force:source:push -u circle_build_$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM
```

and here is the error message coming from the push failing:

```
Successfully created scratch org: 00D2300000091cBEAQ, username: test-w6kin3pwiiyr@example.com
ERROR running force:source:push:  EMFILE: too many open files, open '/tmp/sdx_decomposition_1648223287599/objects/ServiceLevel__c.object-meta.xml'

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: On which version of sfdx are you? You might want to try the latest resp. older versions. How many files does the package have anyway? Maybe add parts of your files to .forceignore and push in stages.

Comment: Hi, Felix.  I am on the latest version of sfdx.  My package is huge - 100 tables, 700 classes, 100 LWCs, 100 VF pages, etc.

Comment: See this [Salesforce bug](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000KTqLQAW&title=sfdx-deploy-error-emfile-too-many-open-files). Go for the .forceignore workaround and avoid to push more than 10 000 files at any time. Reports, test classes... - not everything needs to be pushed in the first round.

Comment: OK, Felix I will try partial pushes.  Thank you for your help.